# Scrolling up triggers both up and down when scrolling up

Tags: jquery

I have a function which should console log `up` when scrolling up and `down` when scrolling down.

Scrolling down works fine, but when scrolling up the console logs both `up` and `down`.

Why isn't it just logging `up` when scrolling up, as it is just logging `down` when scrolling down?

```
function scrollTest() {

        var lastScrollTop = 0;

        $(window).scroll(function(event) {

            var st = $(this).scrollTop();

            if (st > lastScrollTop){
                console.log('down');
            } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
                console.log('up');
            }

            lastScrollTop = st;

        });

    };

$( window ).on( "scroll", function() {

    scrollTest();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to

```
    function scrollTest(){
          var lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
          $(window).scroll(function(event) {

          var st = $(this).scrollTop();

          if (st > lastScrollTop){
              console.log('down');
          } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
              console.log('up');
          }

          lastScrollTop = st;

      });
            }        
    $( window ).on( "scroll", function() {
            scrollTest();
    });
```

The `var lastScrollTop  = 0` was creating the issue. 
Meaning no offense to the other answer or its author, I feel that
It is generally a bad idea to have a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

This fix it:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
function scrollTest() {


    $(window).scroll(function(event) {

        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (st > lastScrollTop){
            console.log('down ' + st + " | " + lastScrollTop);
            lastScrollTop = st;
            return 0;
        } 
        if (st < lastScrollTop) {
            console.log('up ' + st + " | " + lastScrollTop);
            lastScrollTop = st;
            return 0;
        }
      });

    };

$( window ).on( "scroll", function() {

    scrollTest();

});
```

The problem is that `var lastScrollTop = 0;` was getting the value 0 on each scroll... [here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diego_carrascal/pnh7wz1u/5/)